# SQL запрос в Eloquent на Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

Всем добрый вечер. Помогите пож, как мне написать нижеследующий запрос через Eloquent для Laravel.
Столько гуглил не нашел решение, заранее спасибо!

```
select * from table_1 where (id in (select id_1 from table_2 where status = "success"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашёл. Связываем таблицы.

Для первой таблицы *(Модель)* пишем:

```
public function table_1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Vendor\Project\Models\Models1', 'id', 'table_1_column');
}
```

Для второй таблицы *(Модель)* пишем:

```
public function table_2()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Vendor\Project\Models\Models2');
}
```

Далее в коде пишем:

```
$var = Models1::whereHas('data', function ($query) {
     $query->where('status', '=', 'success');
})->get();
```